# Confusing Jupyter Notebook packages on Anaconda: jupyter or notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, package, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I have been wondering about this for a while and cannot seem to find a reliable source to explain this.

I want to install **Jupyter Notebook** to my Conda environment, and when I search for it on https://anaconda.org/, there are 2 very popular packages available and both of them can open a working Jupyter Notebook with no problem.

- https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter
- https://anaconda.org/anaconda/notebook

However, according to the Project Jupyter's [official documentation](https://jupyter.org/install), the pip command to install Jupyter Notebook is:

```bash
pip install notebook
```

And nowhere in the documenation, it mentions anything about this **jupyter** package.

#### Question

So what exactly is this **jupyter** package?

- It does not have any license, no description, no references to the Project Jupyter website, and the package just looks unmaintained with version `1.0.0` for a while now.
- Yet it has `> 200k` total downloads and when installed, it is able to open Jupyter Notebook properly.

I find it very confusing and easy to lead to dependencies problem in the future in Conda environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear from the [Project Jupyter instructions](https://jupyter.org/install) that the canonical package name for installing Jupyter Notebook is `notebook`. There are parallel `jupyter` and `notebook` packages in PyPI as well as the `anaconda` channel you mention. However, it is clear that `notebook` is regularly updated (as of writing, `notebook` on `anaconda` was last updated on 30 July 2022, `jupyter` on 22 January 2017!) The `jupyter` package on PyPI [has the description](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter) "Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go." (However, I tested the `jupyter` anaconda package and it only runs notebook, not eg Jupyterlab.)

I would guess that the `jupyter` package is left over from when Project Jupyter was just notebooks, without other projects like Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Hub. Of course in installing one should follow the official instructions, since the older package is not kept up to date. The fact that it has a lot of downloads only shows (as does this question) that python package management and the Jupyter ecosystem are confusing for many...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for testing the package. I guess I was able to open Jupyter Lab due to have the mixes of both the `jupyter` and `jupyterlab` in my Conda environment. It just looks frustrated to me why neither Anaconda or Project Jupyter has done anything about this. I believe they could either archive `jupyter` or update the description as `deprecated` or something so that people can start installing the right package.

Comment: Yes, `jupyterlab` is a separate package. And you could bring this point up with the developers via eg Discourse or their mailing list, there are links at https://jupyter.org/community